Loop through sheets to remove textboxes and change font color
I am looking for code that will circle through all worksheets and set the font of all cells to black.
Moreover it should remove all textboxes inside and I would be pleased if it could replace them by a new box.
I tried something like this:
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim shp As Shape
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        shp.Delete
    Next shp

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

   Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Select

With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    
  
 End With
Next ws

It works just for the first sheet and it will not remove the textbox.
It is based on a loop code from Microsoft and I tried to find working code which can be simply pasted in the loop.
Why does it stop on the first sheet and only change the color?

This Range - Range("A1") is not qualified, so it assumes ActiveSheet even tho it's in a loop. Add a worksheet qualifier. ws.Range("A1") - Also, there are better ways of doing this which do not involve using Select and Selection that you should consider.

See here for more info on avoiding Select in your code

Thank you. I will try to incorporate your suggestions even though I do not understand them entirely at this point. I will try and maybe I am coming back with new questions  . Thanks!

Loop Through Worksheets and Shapes

Here's a basic code.
Pay attention to the indentation and the location of the loops: you're looping through the worksheets of the workbook (outer loop) and the shapes of each worksheet (inner loop).
The code in your post should fail on the first loop since the worksheet is not set i.e. Dim ws As Worksheet means Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Nothing. Either you have an On Error Resume Next before that you're not showing or copying the code to your post went wrong.
Another crucial issue is explained by braX in your comments.

Sub ChangeFontColorAndDeleteShapes()
    
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape
    
    ' Loop through all worksheets in the workbook.
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        ws.UsedRange.Font.Color = vbBlack
        ' Loop through all shapes in the current worksheet.
        For Each shp In ws.Shapes
            shp.Delete
        Next shp
    Next ws

End Sub


Thank you! I will try your code and then build on it. As you can clearly see I am lacking basic understanding for this and these are my first steps. Therefore I am thankful for your code and explainaitions.
